# set value on multiple row from column based on previous query php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

running the following query ($box is yes or no from previous page):

```
$raw_results = mysqli_query($con,"
SELECT * 
  FROM `tbl_case` 
 WHERE `self_paid` ='$box' 
   AND `case_date_closed` BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate'  
");
```

It displays all the fields correctly, and finishes with another checkbox
with the radio button below, if selected yes, it should set yes to paid_state on all previously returned $id'

```
<h1>    Would you like to set these as paid to self ?
    <form>
    <form action="selfpaid.php" method="POST">
 <input type="radio" name="state" value="yes" checked> Yes<br>
 <input type="radio" name="state" value="no"> no<br>
<input type="submit" style="margin-left:80px; width:150px; height:30px;" value="Set state" />
 </form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['state']) && $_POST['state'] == "yes")
{
 mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE tbl_case SET self_paid = 'yes' WHERE id =     '$id'");
   echo "Setting paid statesucessfull.";
 }
else{
echo "paid_state not set";
}
?>
```

i am guessing it needs to be pulled from the db, and put all those $id in another array var, but i can;t figure out how, and then loop over that array .. can someone point me in the right direction ?